# Top drop down navigation menu displaying the child of the last menu item on right side instead on left side?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a top drop down navigation menu which in which every menu item has child and these children are displaying on right side.

It is fine for all the  menu items except the last one. Because when I hover the mouse over the last menu item the drop down menu appears then when I hover the mouse on a menu item with children that children displays on the right side and hidden because the browser window finishes there.

So what should I do to display the children menu items on the left side when ever the browser window finishes so that the  menu items appears to the users.

Any help please?

**EDIT**
http://harleydragon.info
Please look at this site. Mouse over the Pigeon Forge menu and see its children. That children should be appear on left side because there is no space on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really unclear but I think I understand what is going on...

Either give your last menu item an id (such as `#last-item`), then style the subsequent children to appear on the left (given the `#last-item` id), rather than the right (using your preferred method depending on your situation - ie. position:relative + left, or float, of margin)

```
#menu .children
{
    /* position right */
}

/* "#menu" in the following style is NOT required, 
   I left it in for sake of clarity. */
#menu #last-item .children  
{
    /* position left */
}
```

Also consider using CSS pseudo-classes to style the children of your last element:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

Comment: (just a tip:) I think '.children' in: `#last-item .children` is a bit redundant as ID's are already unique-per-page. Or use the CSS3 property `:last-child` (won't work for lower than IE9)

Comment: Whilst the question is vague and therefore open to interpretation (IMO), the #last-item element above refers to the last parent item in the menu, which gives birth to the children elements below that are in need of styling - in this case #last-item IS required, but I'll edit my answer to clarify this some more :) Also, the link I provided above actually references :last-child

Comment: true, I misunderstood it. My bad :)

Comment: http://harleydragon.info
Please look at this site. Mouse over the Pigeon Forge menu and see its children. That children should be appear on left side because there is no space on the right side.

Comment: Yes, the method I have suggested above will fix this for you. If you give the very last `<li>` within the `.dropdown` ul tag an id of `#last-item`, then use the style `#last-item ul li` to appropriately style the children to appear on the left instead of the right. You can also achieve this using `.dropdown:last-child` (but be aware of browser compatibility)

Comment: It did not solved the problem. Please tell me another method if possible please.